# Wrapped text in <p> changes <div> position

Tags: html, css

I have 4 `div`s with defined heights & widths, each contains a `p` element. In one case, the text from one `p` wraps to a second line. This changes the position of that `div`. Dev tools doesn't show any change in margin or padding for the parent `div` or the `div` whose position moved.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="holder">
  <div class="box"><p>I got words</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got words too</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got no words</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got so many words that they wrap down</p></div>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```css
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

and here's a link to the pen: https://codepen.io/Yeti_Detective/pen/rwNVXV

Comment: Add `vertical-align:top` to the `.box` class. Otherwise, it aligns them according to the baseline of text, which for the two-line one is the bottom of the second line. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwojGb

Comment: Alternatively, update your CSS to the modern age and use `display: flex` on the container. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GERpze

Comment: I would use span, and the css to manipulate your effect from there.

Comment: Thank you all. I went with `display: flex` on the parent & `margin: auto` on the bbys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `display:inline-block`, you need be aware that `vertical-align:baseline` - the default value - is still in effect.

What this means is that the inline-block elements are aligned according to the text baseline, which in the case of the two-line element is according to the bottom line.

```css
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

#marker {
  position: absolute;
  width: 304px;
  margin-top: -1em;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div class="box"><p>I got words</p><div id="marker"></div></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got so many words that they wrap down</p></div>
</div>
```

There are two ways to fix this. Option 1 is to add `vertical-align:top` to the boxes. This will do exactly what it says.

Option 2, which personally I prefer, is using `display:flex` on the container. You'll need `justify-content: center` to centre-align the boxes.

```css
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 0 4px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div class="box"><p>I got words</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got words too</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got no words</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got so many words that they wrap down</p></div>
</div>
```

Done :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed `vertical-align:top;` property Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/28afvwbd/1/

CSS code here

```
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving `.box` the style `vertical-align: top;` should do the trick.

```css
#holder {
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(25, 25, 25, 0.9);
  text-align: center;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div class="box"><p>I got words</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got words too</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got no words</p></div>
  <div class="box"><p>I got a lot of words, but I no longer wrap down!</p></div>
</div>
```